# what's the memory location way while using a value type as a paramter

Tags: c#, memory-management, value-type, reference-type

I know the general difference between value type and reference type, and I also know when using a value type in a reference type, this value type is actually on the heap.

ex:

```
class ClassA{
   public DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 3, 1, 7, 0, 0);
}
```

when

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
```

the date1 is on heap

My question is

if we use this date1 as a parameter in a method, what's the memory location behavior?

```
public void methodA(DateTime dt)
{
//do sth with the dt
}
```

invoke the method

```
methodA(new ClassA().date1);
```

Option 1: Just copies one date1 reference
Option 2: Or copy date1 data to run

**UPDATE**:
After reading the "the truth about value types", i realised there are some uncertainties in my assumption. At least I should give a context like. "in the Microsoft implementation of C# on the desktop CLR, value types are stored on the stack when the value is a local variable or temporary that is not a closed-over local variable of a lambda or anonymous method, and the method body is not an iterator block, and the jitter chooses to not enregister the value."

**Update2**:
The reason I asked about this is I want to understand some code snippet on http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/assault-by-gc.html

> change Customer from a class to a struct (only within this crazy code)
>
> change the main store from a List to a Customer[]
>
> change the subsets from List to List, specifically the
>   offset intothe main Customer[]

```
void SomethingComplex(ref Customer customer) {...}
...
int custIndex = ...
SomethingComplex(ref customers[custIndex]);
```

Comment: You assumptions about where value types live are an implementation details and not always correct. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx

Comment: You mean, using a value type as a local varaible in a reference type, in some case,the value type can live on stack as well? Can you give a example.

Comment: I suggest reading the article I linked to. What the runtime does now does not mean it may not change (or that a different VM is doing it differently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime` is a value type, so the value will be copied on method invocation.

Comment: thanks. I think now I can understand sth mentioned in @Marc Gravell 's blog http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/assault-by-gc.html.